# How can i get a string from a iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

i have the next code:

```
        List<Tienda> tiendas = saxparser.parse();
        Iterator it = tiendas.iterator();
```

it is an "iterator" that contais 3 rows with the next format:

```
latitud=XXX
longitud=xxx
nombre=xxxx
```

Then, how can i get the value of it(1)(latitud) 
(I dont know how can i explain more easy in english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're understanding it correctly, but an iterator allow you to move through the list and get its element.

Your list is a list of element type "Tienda". When you use it.Next(), this will move the cursor to the next element and return the item. Assuming latitude, longitude, and nombre are properties within the class "Tienda", then your code should be something like this if you were to print out the value of those properties to the console.

```
List<Tienda> tiendas = saxparser.parse();
Iterator it = tienda.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Tienda temp = it.Next();
    system.out.println(temp.latitude + ", " + temp.longitude + ", " + temp.longitude);
}
```